# setting up kendo ui dropdownlist based on condition

Tags: razor, kendo-ui

I have the following dropdownlist i would like to set to dropdownlist to certain value if the value from ViewBag.ServerId then set to 2

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [
                        { text: "Selection 1", value: "1" },
                        { text: "Selection 2", value: "2" }

        ];

 $("#Cust").kendoDropDownList({

                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    dataSource: data,
                    index: 0,
                    optionLabel: {
                        text: "Please Select",
                        value: ""
                    }



                });
        var dropdownlist = $("#Cust").data("kendoDropDownList");

        });


    </script>

    <div>
    @if (ViewBag.serverId == 3)
    {
        so i would like to do something like this however i could reference dropdownlist.
        dropdownlist.select(dropdownlist.ul.children().eq(2));
    }
    else
    {


    }
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **condition** your selection something like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {            

        $("#Cust").kendoDropDownList({    
            ...
            index: (parseInt(@ViewBag.ServerId) === 3) ? 2 : 0,
            ...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can do like this:

@if (ViewBag.serverId == 3)
    {

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
           $("#Cust").data("kendoDropDownList").select(dropdownlist.ul.children().eq(2));
        });
        </script>
    }

    else
    {


    }
You know, if there are mutiple jQuery dom ready event in one page. They will be executed by order.
If the Kendo dropdown list component initialized in the prev context, I think you get the component instance from the element.
```